# PostgreSQL port 5432 already in use // Forgot user password

Tags: postgresql, macos

I am having some trouble for a couple of days now regarding the use of postgreSQL
(version of macos : 10.15.4 )

1. I lost the user password and cannot log into the psql console because of that
2. I tried to launch PosgreSQL 12 app to visualise my DBs better and somehow my port is always in use

My first question is :

- How can I reset all my postgresql config to start over and reset the suers and the passwords ? (I do not have important data on my DB)

I've tried to 
`brew uninstall postgresql`
and 
`brew remove postgresql`

Nothing functionned on that end

Second question and second possibility

- I have tried to follow the indication in that solution : https://github.com/dwyl/learn-postgresql/issues/60

When launching the app it says to me port 5432 is already in use

I encountered a strange behaviour :

`lsof -i TCP:5432`

gives me two lines of processes listening in the port
I tried to kill the related pid
it works
But then another new pid comes up and uses port 5432 and the pid number are incremented as if no matter what happens my postgres cammand is regenerated an my port 5432 in use.

With this I am stuck with an app I cannot use and a command line where I cannot connect on.

Do you have any idea how to reset or resolve the issue please ?

Edit
It seems that every 10s my postgre log file is incremented with this

```
    2020-04-28 19:28:52.579 CEST [12186] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0, compiled by Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59), 64-bit
2020-04-28 19:28:52.626 CEST [12186] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address already in use
2020-04-28 19:28:52.626 CEST [12186] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2020-04-28 19:28:52.626 CEST [12186] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
2020-04-28 19:28:52.626 CEST [12186] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2020-04-28 19:28:52.626 CEST [12186] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2020-04-28 19:28:52.626 CEST [12186] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2020-04-28 19:28:52.649 CEST [12186] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Thanks for any advice on that!
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

After my computer restarts, sometimes I'll get a port 5432 already in use error even though no processes are running on port 5432.

What works for me:

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

This shows all processes running under the postgres user.

```
sudo pkill -u postgres
```

This kills those processes

Answer (score 0):

Try killing process using `launchctl`

List all running process using :

```
launchctl list
```

Kill the process using :

```
launchtl kill -9 {pid}
```

Comment: Hello Rajat 
I already tried that it didn't work. My computer after reboot does not have process on port 5432
`lsof -i TCP:5432`

But stille I cannot run postgres app

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the postgres via brew then check the process status.

ps -ef | grep postgres

Now, stop the process through brew.

brew services stop PostgreSQL

Now, start the Postgres.
Don't start via brew, If you start then pg_ctl start won't work. You will get port conflict and the address already in use WARNINGS.

If u start the process via brew then check the postmaster.id
Stop the process via the brew command.

Then start Postgres.
pg_ctl start